# Multiple select statements in same function

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have the following function:

```
DELIMITER $$
create function fp_v2.fp_splitadjprice (id char(8), startdate date)
returns float 
begin
declare splitfactor float;
declare splitadjprice float;
declare spinofffactor float;
set splitfactor = 1.0;

select splitfactor = fp_v2.fp_splitfactor_prices(id, startdate);
select splitadjprice = convert(float,p_price * splitfactor)
from fp_v2.fp_basic_prices p
where fsym_id = id and p_date = startdate;
return splitadjprice;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I get an error message at the 2nd select statement saying "expected a ( or with".

I really don't understand the syntax of MySQL workbench. It seems pretty random to me. Like when should I put ; and when should I not?. What are the rules?

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: All stupid questions welcome as long as they show some research effort.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages in order to better understand what is (and is not) appropriate to ask here before posting.

Comment: That's commendable, but it is very much unsuitable for this particular site. Perhaps you can find a suitable MySQL channel over on the Stack Overflow [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) where this sort of thing would be perfectly acceptable (but take it slow until you get a feel for what's acceptable in any particular room).

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I tried to post a question instead :)

Comment: @Chris nominated for reopening

Comment: Also nominated for reopening. But most like it you need ` SELECT ... INTO @variable`  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html

Comment: The convert sintaxis is also wrong. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html

Comment: Not sure why. But variables on functions doesnt use @. user variables in a separated query does.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Alright, so leaving them out of the functions as I have here is perfectly fine?

Comment: Yes the error is becasue you dont use `SELECT INTO` This is an small example. for `SELECT INTO` 'https://rextester.com/WNYUQW35138

Comment: Because what you are doing right now is create an alias. `SELECT Alias = field` == `SELECT field as Alias` What you want is assign the result to a variable and that is with `SELECT INTO`  ... here is another example using multiple functions. https://rextester.com/IDPY20240

Comment: As I also said, you problem is with `CAST()` first the type go as second parameter like `CAST(value, type)` second float isnt valid type for CAST you need use `DECIMAL(x,y)` check here https://rextester.com/CVJM89914

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183570/discussion-between-chris-and-juan-carlos-oropeza).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use `SELECT .. INTO` to update your variables.

convert sintaxis is `CONVERT(value, type)` and you cant use `FLOAT` as type need use `DECIMAL` and you probably dont need it anyway because your both variable are float already.

```
DELIMITER $$
create function fp_v2.fp_splitadjprice (id char(8), startdate date)
returns float 
begin
declare splitfactor float;
declare splitadjprice float;
declare spinofffactor float;
set splitfactor = 1.0;

SELECT fp_v2.fp_splitfactor_prices(id, startdate) INTO splitfactor ;

SELECT convert(p_price * splitfactor, DECIMAL (10,4) INTO splitadjprice 
FROM fp_v2.fp_basic_prices p
WHERE fsym_id = id and p_date = startdate;

return splitadjprice;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```